# Python Sublist Creation

Tags: python, sublist

I have a list which is shuffled, and then I want it to be broken down into 6 sublists of 6 elements each (there are 26 elements in the original list). I know it needs to be done by creating a sublist via ranges (eg. 0-5,6-11 etc.) but can't find out how. It should be quite straight forward! Here's my code so far:

```
import random

characters = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];

random.shuffle(characters)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
>>> import string
>>> import random
>>>
>>> chars = list(string.uppercase + string.digits)
>>> random.shuffle(chars)
>>>
>>> [chars[i:i + 6] for i in range(0, len(chars), 6)]
[['U', 'I', 'X', '6', 'Q', 'L'],
 ['Y', 'J', 'C', 'S', '8', '0'],
 ['A', 'R', '5', 'F', 'T', 'W'],
 ['N', 'B', 'E', '2', '1', 'V'],
 ['9', 'K', 'O', 'P', '7', '4'],
 ['G', 'M', 'Z', '3', 'D', 'H']]
```

- `chars[i:i + 6]` creates a sublist of length `6` that starts at position `i`.
- `range(0, len(chars), 6)` loops over the range from `0` to `len(chars)` in increments of `6`:

  ```
  >>> range(0, len(chars), 6)
  [0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30]
  ```

Answer (score 1):

using `itertools.islice()`:

```
In [246]: characters = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];

In [247]: it=iter(characters)

In [248]: [list(islice(it,6)) for _ in range(6)]
Out[248]: 
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B'],
 ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
 ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N'],
 ['O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
 ['U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']]
```

`iter(characters)` : creates an iterator of `characters` list.

`islice(iterator,len)` :returns a slice of the iterator of `len=6`. Islice object is an iterator itself, So, you need to pass the `islice` object to `list()` in order to fetch it's content.

The `6` passed to `range` can be obtained by :

```
In [2]: int(len(characters)/6)
Out[2]: 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on itertools grouper recipe

Relies on [itertools.izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) and self incremental or iterator

```
>>> list(izip_longest(*[iter(characters)] * 6))
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'), ('I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N'), ('O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'), ('U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z')]
```